# Count number of times a character appears in R df row

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to get a count of the number of times the character 'V' appears in each row in my dataframe in R. I have a df that contains dictionary entries (DutchOrthography), their pronunciations (IPA), and a column which contains their vowels replaced with the letter V (CV). I want to use the CV column to count the number of vowels in each word.

```
dutch4 <- data.frame (DutchOrthography = c(‘aagtappel’, ‘aagt’, ‘aaibaar’, ‘aaibaarheid’, ‘aaien’),
                      IPA = c(‘aːxtɑppɛl’, ‘aːxt’, ‘aːjɪbaːr’, ‘aːjɪbaːrhɛjt’, ‘aːjɛn’),
                      CV = c(‘VːxtVppVl’, ‘Vːxt’, ‘VːjVbVːr’, ‘VːjVbVːrhVjt’, ‘VːjVn’)
                      )
```

df looks like this:
[image]

I've tried doing this with rowSums:
 `dutch4$vowelCount <- rowSums(dutch4 == "V")`

It creates the desired column 'vowelCount', but it only contains zeros. It's not counting the number of times 'V' appears in a column, probably because it's looking rows which contain only 'V', and it's not counting the number of times 'V' appears among other characters in a string for each row.

Is there a way to count the instances of 'V' among the strings in each row (or really just the CV column) and add that to a new column?

Comment: Does `V:` signify that there are, two of the same vowels in row, and a second `V:` would say, also two, but different vowel from `V:` to the left? No, clearly not. What is `:` signifying?And why does is seem to vary around `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the "V:" means.
But in case the CV columns is accurate, and "V:" counts as one V, we need only `stringr::str_count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dutch4 |> 
    mutate(vowelCount = str_count(CV, "V"))

 DutchOrthography          IPA           CV vowelCount
1        aagtappel    aːxtɑppɛl    VːxtVppVl          3
2             aagt         aːxt         Vːxt          1
3          aaibaar     aːjɪbaːr     VːjVbVːr          3
4      aaibaarheid aːjɪbaːrhɛjt VːjVbVːrhVjt          4
5            aaien        aːjɛn        VːjVn          2
```

**data**

```
data.frame (DutchOrthography = c('aagtappel', 'aagt', 'aaibaar', 'aaibaarheid', 'aaien'),
                      IPA = c('aːxtɑppɛl', 'aːxt', 'aːjɪbaːr', 'aːjɪbaːrhɛjt', 'aːjɛn'),
                      CV = c('VːxtVppVl', 'Vːxt', 'VːjVbVːr', 'VːjVbVːrhVjt', 'VːjVn')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.frame (DutchOrthography = c('aagtappel', 'aagt', 'aaibaar', 'aaibaarheid', 'aaien'),
                      IPA = c('aːxtɑppɛl', 'aːxt', 'aːjɪbaːr', 'aːjɪbaːrhɛjt', 'aːjɛn'),
                      CV = c('VːxtVppVl', 'Vːxt', 'VːjVbVːr', 'VːjVbVːrhVjt', 'VːjVn')
) %>% 
  mutate(new1=str_extract_all(CV, 'V')) %>% 
  unnest(cols = new1) %>% 
  group_by(DutchOrthography) %>% 
  mutate(n=n()) %>% slice_tail(n=1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 5
# Groups:   DutchOrthography [5]
  DutchOrthography IPA          CV           new1      n
  <chr>            <chr>        <chr>        <chr> <int>
1 aagt             aːxt         Vːxt         V         1
2 aagtappel        aːxtɑppɛl    VːxtVppVl    V         3
3 aaibaar          aːjɪbaːr     VːjVbVːr     V         3
4 aaibaarheid      aːjɪbaːrhɛjt VːjVbVːrhVjt V         4
5 aaien            aːjɛn        VːjVn        V         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `lengths` of `gregexpr` matches, without the need of using extra packages for this task.

```
> transform(dutch4, v_count=lengths(gregexpr('V', dutch4$CV)))
  DutchOrthography          IPA           CV v_count
1        aagtappel    aːxtɑppɛl    VːxtVppVl       3
2             aagt         aːxt         Vːxt       1
3          aaibaar     aːjɪbaːr     VːjVbVːr       3
4      aaibaarheid aːjɪbaːrhɛjt VːjVbVːrhVjt       4
5            aaien        aːjɛn        VːjVn       2
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dutch4)
structure(list(DutchOrthography = c("aagtappel", "aagt", "aaibaar", 
"aaibaarheid", "aaien"), IPA = c("aːxtɑppɛl", "aːxt", "aːjɪbaːr", 
"aːjɪbaːrhɛjt", "aːjɛn"), CV = c("VːxtVppVl", "Vːxt", 
"VːjVbVːr", "VːjVbVːrhVjt", "VːjVn")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```